# Using cortex for scraping metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, weave

I'm running [cortex](https://cortexmetrics.io/) on kubernetes in a dev environment to curate a dataset of metrics from multiple applications.

From what I'm reading, cortex utilizes a lot of prometheus source code. Is there a way to configure cortex to scrape metrics like prometheus (based on annotations, maybe?) without having to run instances of prometheus?

This is just for some research, not for production

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Grafana cloud agent](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/03/18/introducing-grafana-cloud-agent-a-remote_write-focused-prometheus-agent-that-can-save-40-on-memory-usage/). There is also more lightweight scraper for Prometheus metrics - [vmagent](https://victoriametrics.github.io/vmagent.html).

Answer (score -1):

According to the maintainers, there's no way to do this